# Infinite union of an open/closed interval

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given the problem
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n} \right]
$$

Would the answer be $ \left( 0, 1 \right] $
or $ \left[ 0, 1 \right] $?

We were trying to determine whether the limit $\frac{1}{\infty}$ is included in the interval as $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: The question is just whether $0$ is in the given union $\bigcup U_n$. By definition is is true iff $0 \in U_n$ for some $n$. Can you check this?

Comment: OP: do you know the definition of union? (It is one of the ZF axioms...)

Comment: $1-\frac{1}{n}\ge\frac{1}{n}$ when $n\ge2$.

Comment: There are no limits in this question.

Comment: Give that $1-\frac{1}{n}> \frac{1}{n}$ except when $n=1,,2, most of these intervals are empty.

Comment: But no, the limit $\frac{1}{\infty}$ is not included. In these cases, the $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is just notation for $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N^{+}}$.

Comment: Okay, so if the left side of the interval is greater than the right side, the interval is considered empty. This is a question we just had on an exam that I was debating with a friend. Because the intervals where $n \geq 2$ are empty, the answer would have to be $\left( 0, 1 \right]$ ?

Comment: @Jonathan Correct.

Comment: You may have a misunderstanding of the notation.  $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ means $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N}A_n.$.... So $0\in \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ iff $0\in A_n$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $(0,1]$. We denote the intervals $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, and the union of them all $A$.

Proof of first inclusion :
$$
\Big (1 - \frac{1}{1} ,\frac{1}{1} \Big ] = (0,1] \quad \text{so} \quad (0,1] \subset A.
$$
Obviously, $A \subset [0,1]$, and $1-1/n \ge 0$ and $1/n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $0 \notin A$, so $A \subset (0,1]$.

Thus, the limit is not in the interval.